# activerecord relation model name displaying twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Good afternoon,

First post here. I have done a bit of research into this error and not finding anything helpful to me, and because stackoverflow community is my number 1 place to find a answer. I thought why not ask here.

I have created a new rails app, and have created a relation between the order and order_item model.

> app/models/order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: 'customer_id'
  belongs_to :shop

  has_many :order_items, dependent: :destroy
end
```

> app/models/order_item.rb

```
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

The relationship between customer and order is working because I have created a record for both. 
eg

```
Customer.create(:customer_attributes).orders.create
```

but when I try to access or create a order item

```
Customer.first.orders.first.order_items.first || Customer.first.orders.first.order_items.create
```

I get the following error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'order_order_items'

my question is, why is it looking for the table name with the prefix twice?

below is what my migration files look like for both models

> db/migrate/orders

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.integer :shop_id
      t.integer :customer_id
      t.string :status
      t.string :additional_info
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

> db/migrate/order_items

```
class CreateOrderItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :order_items do |t|
      t.integer :order_id
      t.integer :menu_item_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. New to ruby and rails, so please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Cheers

Comment: can you paste result of `Customer.first.orders.first` here?

Comment: could you please paste a copy of your `db/schema.rb` so we can see what table names were actually assigned?

Comment: Strange, everything is looking good. It would be expecting this error if you would have specified a `has_and_belongs_to_many` (instead of the `has_many`). I want to know when exactly you get this error. So Instead of showing us that one liner, which could fail at many places, does it fail when 1) retrieving the first order? 2) the first order-item? or 3) creating the first order item?

Comment: Are you trying to make a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship? I'm thinking you are by the way your CreateOrderItems migration is written and by its name.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

Hey guys! Thank for fast replies, I figured out what the problem was. Earlier in the project I had tried to implement namespacing into the models and this is what was causing the trouble. Once i moved all models directly under the app/models dir and restarted the console all worked 100%. So im guessing I dont understand enough yet of how rails handles the namespacing, but im going to try the namespacing at later stage. For now I just need a quick prototype up an running to demo to a few clients.

Once again thanks for the fast replies.